# Recently I cannot install software, I am using Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: software-installation, software-center, 17.04

Recently, I could not install some new software such as gnucash and vlc neither from Ubuntu Software nor from terminal, other software download just fine. I am using Ubuntu 17.04, is it because it is on EOL?

Comment: It is EOL, as a non-LTS (Long Term Support) version it is only supported for 9 months. You can move to 17.10 by using the answers at https://askubuntu.com/q/91815/320386 . The next LTS will be 18.04, or you could alternatively install 16.04, the current LTS.